# Creating a "forum" - showing last post or last commented post

Tags: sql

thanks for reading!

Im creating a forum just using categories and posts. I'd like (as most forums do) to show the last commented post or the last created post (which ever is newer) next to the category name.

I've found [this related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/698438/ordering-wordpress-posts-by-most-recent-comment). However I'm not good reading SQL queries, Im not sure if any of this queries work as I'd expect.

```
select wp_posts.*,
coalesce(
    (
        select max(comment_date)
        from $wpdb->comments wpc
        where wpc.comment_post_id = wp_posts.id
    ),
    wp_posts.post_date
) as mcomment_date
from $wpdb->posts wp_posts
where post_type = 'post'
and post_status = 'publish' 
order by mcomment_date desc
limit 10
```

Is there any other way you would achieve this?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You can add the standard taxonomy joins to the query:

```
global $wpdb;
$cat_id = 79; // Whatever.
$sql = "
    select wp_posts.*,
    coalesce(
        (
            select max(comment_date)
            from $wpdb->comments wpc
            where wpc.comment_post_id = wp_posts.id
        ),
        wp_posts.post_date
    ) as mcomment_date
    from $wpdb->posts wp_posts
    JOIN $wpdb->term_relationships AS tr ON wp_posts.ID = tr.object_id
    JOIN $wpdb->term_taxonomy AS tt ON tr.term_taxonomy_id = tt.term_taxonomy_id
    where post_type = 'post'
    and post_status = 'publish'
    AND tt.term_id = $cat_id AND tt.taxonomy = 'category'
    order by mcomment_date desc
    limit 1
";
$ret = $wpdb->get_results($sql);
```